# Search Result missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have SharePoint 2016 I use it as search center  my issue is that when I search for something that include symbols like -_@ I can not get any result but ex : 23_Project I get no result but If I put A slash like \  23_Project it will read the symbol and give me the result so how to make SharePoint Read any symbols automatically

Regards,

Comment: sorry the if I put a slash like that 23\_project I can get my result

Comment: Provide a code example of how do you **search for something that include symbols like -_@**

Comment: just put a \ before it and it will work but I do not wanna users do that

Comment: so if I write   \   before any symbols I can get the result if not I will not get any result